# Evict cache from Cache Tag Helper

Tags: asp.net-core

I have in a razor page something like this

```
<cache vary-by-user="true" expires-after="TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)" vary-by="@culture">
   <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg s-navbar">
   </nav>
</cache>
```

And it works. But the content of the cache sometimes is changed and the cache values have to take the new values. I do not want to tell the customer that he has to wait 30 minutes before accessing again the page in order to see the correct values.

Is there a way to manually evict the cache from the Cache Tag Helper?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think that's possible. You can add the asp-append-version attribute to <link>, <script>, and <img> elements to provide cache-busting capabilities based on the file’s contents. But you're caching a navbar. Look, caching is super easy; the hardest part is invalidating the cache. But to answer your question; Yes, I can think of 1 thing in this case. Clear your MemoryCache by rebooting the app - since the cache taghelper leverages the MemoryCache.

Comment: I found a solution as mentioned in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69222962/how-to-clear-the-cache-tag-helper-programmatically-in-asp-net-5/74234425#74234425