# How to clear the Cache Tag Helper programmatically in ASP.NET 5?

Tags: asp.net, caching, razor

In ASP.NET 5 a cache can be made in a Razor template as follows:

```
<cache expires-after="@TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)">
</cache>
```

I want to be able to clear all caches programmatically, is this possible?

My issue is I am creating the cache for a website and when a user changes content I want to clear all caches as what needs to show on the front end may change. I am not interested in time based expiration. Is this possible?

**Update 1**

Based on Robert Harvey's comment, I tried [this](https://ianvink.wordpress.com/2020/08/14/asp-net-core-clearing-the-entire-imemorycache/) in a Controller but it did not clear the cache:

```
public TestController(IMemoryCache cache)
{
  _cache = cache;
}


public IActionResult ClearCache()
{
  PropertyInfo prop = _cache.GetType().GetProperty("EntriesCollection", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);
  object secretCache = prop?.GetValue(_cache);
  MethodInfo clearMethod = secretCache?.GetType().GetMethod("Clear", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
  clearMethod?.Invoke(secretCache, null);
  return new OkResult();

}
```

Comment: Look [here](http://www.liangshunet.com/en/202009/658197699.htm).

Comment: Thanks, tried something similar to that but it doesn't work :-(

Comment: I tried the same and unfortunately, the key does not even exist in the EntriesCollection? I am also using the memory cache.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve this by using the **vary-by** attribute.

I had a static string ***CurrentCacheVersion*** that stored a GUID and this was changed when I pass a querystring "?clearcache=yes" on the homepage.

```
If(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(clearcache)){
 StaticHelper.CurrentCacheVersion = Guide.NewId().ToString()
}
```

And in my cache tag, I do vary-by="@StaticHelper.CurrentCacheVersion"

```
<cache vary-by="@StaticHelper.CurrentCacheVersion" expires-after="@TimeSpan.FromDays(5)">
 // my cached objects
</cache>
```